# Is there any API to implement way2sms app for iphone..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, networking

hii is there an API to implement way2sms app to send text messages to india.The App already exists in Android.I want to implement the same features in iphone also.Any idea to start the project.

Answer (score 2):

There is already an app at the app store that sends free SMS accoss India
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smsglobal/id570193291?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about this. Just hit it on google. May be this would help you!!

https://www.mashape.com/blaazetech/way2sms

And it is clearly mentioned in this site, there is no API for way2sms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to get the code from .apk android apps and get the api from this